# How to parse a record into two by splitting one field and repeating the others

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing

I have the following table:

I have the following table:

```
Patent      AssigneeName                        AssigneeUnparsed
-------     --------------                      ---------------
D452605     Louis Vuitton Malletier, S.A.       Paris_None_FR
D452606     Nike, Inc.                          Beaverton_OR_US
D452607     Salomon S.A.; First Technology      Metz-Tessy_None_FR
```

There are some instances where there are two assignee names in the assignee name field and they are separated by a ;

is there a way for me to have MySQL go through and separate them when it does occur, and then repeat all of the data from the other fields in the new record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can have at maximum two assignee names, I would use an INSERT query and then an UPDATE query that make use of [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) like this:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable
SELECT Patent, TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(AssigneeName, ';', -1)), AssigneeUnparsed
FROM yourtable
WHERE AssigneeName LIKE '%;%';

UPDATE yourtable
SET AssigneeName = TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(AssigneeName, ';', -1))
WHERE AssigneeName LIKE '%;%';
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7001/1).